# update one row in a table from another having multiple records

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have table having unique control numbers  and other table having multiple control numbers  i want to update first table with the data of other ;
example

table 1

```
cont_no         purchase_id
1
2
3
```

table 2

```
cont_no      Purchase_id
1            Raj
1            swaj
2            dim
2            kim
2            lim
```

i want `table 1` AS

```
1      RAJ,SWAJ
2      DIM,KIM,TIM
```

How to do this?

Comment: use pivot or unpivot for the select command and when you have the correct format in the select just insert select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
UPDATE
T1
SET
T1.Purchase_id = T2.data
FROM TABLE_1 T1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    SS.cont_no,
    (SELECT US.Purchase_id +'; '
    FROM TABLE_2 US
    WHERE US.cont_no = SS.cont_no
            FOR XML PATH('')) [data]
    FROM TABLE_1 SS
    GROUP BY SS.cont_no, SS.Purchase_id
) T2 ON T1.cont_no = T2.cont_no
```

Thanks
Manoj